# Accessing an instance's methond from a function in another module

Tags: python, class, import, module, instance

Noob question.

I have the following simple code:

```
class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foo"

    def bar(self):
        self.foo = "bar"

def action():
    a = input("Anything>")
    spam.bar()
    print(spam.foo)

spam = Test()

action()
```

It displays, as expected, "bar".

When I split it into two files:
test_main.py:

```
from test_module import action

class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "foo"

    def bar(self):
        self.foo = "bar"


spam = Test()

action()
```

And test_module.py:

```
def action():
    a = input("Anything>")
    spam.bar()
    print(spam.foo)
```

Function action() cant' access object "spam":

```
  File "test_main.py", line 14, in <module>
    action()
  File "/home/krzysztof/Documents/dev/Python Crash Course/12/test_module.py", line 3, in action
    spam.bar()
NameError: name 'spam is not defined'
```

I know that this kind of access is possible, but I can't find information on how to do it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You were previously able to access `spam` because it was a global variable in the same file. You cannot access globals from a different file directly.

The correct way to do this would be to change `action()` to take spam as a parameter:

```
def action(spam):
    a = input("Anything>")
    spam.bar()
    print(spam.foo)
```

and then call it by using `action(spam)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass `spam` the instance of your class to your action function as a parameter. And change the definition of your function.

**test_main.py**

```
from test_module import action 
class Test(): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.foo = "foo" 
    def bar(self): 
        self.foo = "bar" 

spam = Test() 
action(spam)
```

**test_module.py**

```
def action(spam): 
    a = input("Anything>") 
    spam.bar() 
    print(spam.foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are importing the test module file, the entire code from that file is run before importing. So the spam variable does not exist in the test_module file.
you should rather use spam as an argument in the action function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
from test_main import bar
```

and you can use something like this format

```
from FOLDER_NAME import FILENAME
from FILENAME import CLASS_NAME FUNCTION_NAME
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the problem. If this were not an error, it would certainly be leading to a circular import.